# MVC ListBox Posting back only one value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, devexpress

I am trying to post selected values from ListBoxFor back to controller, but the there is always only one selected value.

My model:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> RegionsList { get; set; }
public string[] Regions { get; set; }
```

My View:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.Regions, Model.RegionsList)
```

Im selecting two items, with "Id" 3 and 5. Jquery $("#Regions").val() give me:

```
$("#Regions").val();
["3", "5"]
```

But after post my model has only:

```
"3"
```

I was trying to change string[] to IEnumerable but no results. It's always only one value while posting to controller. Do you have any idea what is the problem ?

Comment: change your `public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> RegionsList { get; set; }` property to `public MultiSelectList RegionsList { get; set; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Propably I found the solution. There is a problem with devexpress model binding:
https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T124733

Comment: You should property tag you question!! (the code works fine in MVC)

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I do not know that this is something wrong with devexpress library.

Answer (score 0):

I usually implement a SelectList model if I need to persist multiple selected items. Then you can use a multi select list like this:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(
    x => x[i].SelectedItems, 
    new MultiSelectList(Model[i].Items, "Value", "Text", Model[i].SelectedItems)
)
```

Comment: Might be worth expanding your code to show where `i` comes from i.e. `for loop`. Just to give a bit more clarity.

Comment: I forgot to add that Im using this while editing Devexpress GridView table. I just started new project without devexpress, only simple model, controller and view. And everything is fine. So there is a problem with model devexpress model binding.